# CGI scripts won't execute on website

Tags: apache, webserver

I have a website up and running on the Apache webserver, but the CGI scripts in `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables` will not run.  Instead, the text of the file loads in the browser instead.

I made the following changes to `httpd.conf`:

1. Added the following line to the LoadModules group:

   `LoadModule cgi_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so`
2. Uncomment the following line (by removing the #):

   `AddHandler cgi_script .cgi`
3. Added this to the virtual host file for the specific site:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:81>
>     DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/"
>     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/"
>     <Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/">
>     AllowOverride none
>     Options +ExecCGI
>     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
>   </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

I am able to run the Perl scripts from the command line without an issue.

Note: this is on High Sierra.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about web development.

Comment: @Jaime This question is not at all about web-development. It is how to install web site programs on your Mac. It could be for example an image gallery program, GitWeb, MovableType, or something different. This is just about how to configure the built-in webserver that comes with macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This absolutely is on topic as long as the host OS is mac or the hardware is mac or the client is mac. It could be on topic other places too, but we wouldn’t migrate away from here or close unless it was requested by OP and on topic elsewhere.

Comment: @jksoegaard my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you're running into one of the following problems:

**Wrong handler name**: In your question, you wrote that you had the following line:

```
AddHandler cgi_script .cgi
```

The underscore is supposed to be a hyphen here, so change that to:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

**Wrong file extension**: Your have specified in your configuration that your Perl scripts are named `something.cgi`. Some actually have their files named `something.pl` instead. If that is the case for you, you'll need to extend both of your AddHandler lines to the following:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

**Permissions:** The Perl scripts needs to have the executable permission bit set in order to be executed as a CGI-script. This means that you have to run a command such as this:

`chmod a+x /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/yourscript.cgi`

You would have to replace "yourscript.cgi" with the actual filename of your script.

**Restart needed:** You need to ensure that the Apache webserver program is actually reloaded or restarted after you change your configuration files. Do this by running the following command:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Comment: Thanks for this info.  So, I followed your instructions and was able to designate a folder within the website for script execution and it worked.  However, I want to run them from the CGI-Executables folder as mentioned above.  I enable this with [ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/"] in the vhosts files but I get the error in the log:  [authz_core:error] [pid *] [client *] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/. It seems like ScriptAlias isn't doing what it's supposed to...?

Comment: So I solved it!  I added this after the ScriptAlias command in the vhosts file: `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/">
        AllowOverride none
        Options ExecCGI 
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        Require all granted
    </Directory>`